# Setting HTTPOnly Cookies on a Golang Backend and Flutter Front-end

Tags: dart, http, go, flutter-web, cookie-httponly

I have spent the entire day looking for an answer to this, and i have not been able.

I am trying to learn Flutter as a front-end framework. in the past i built my webpages with html, css, and vanilla js, but i was able to interpolate dynamic data from the server with php.

I would like to use httpOnly cookies for authenticating user sessions, as i have in the past with php. I'm open to other secure methods, but i am not interested in JWT.

Obviously i cannot access httpOnly cookies from my Flutter App, but i can access them with Golang, which i use for serving the html build, and on my api endpoints.

What i want to do is either, read the httpOnly cookie in golang, and then pass some information into my flutter build to be parsed at runtime, or somehow return an httpOnly cookie from an api endpoint, and persist that to the client that made the call, but i cannot for the life of me figure out how to do either.

I am open to ANY suggestions.

tl;dr on a server with golang backend and flutter front end, how do i read an httpOnly cookie in golang and based on that value, populate values in the flutter front end at runtime, or pass a variable from golang http.HandleFunc that can be read by Flutter at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

you can access a cookie by its name in Go through the request `r *http.Request`

```
var myToken string

cookie, err := r.Cookie("myToken")
if err != nil {
    myToken = ""
} else {
    myToken = cookie.Value
}
```

you can then do user lookup or anything with that token inside a [middleware](https://drstearns.github.io/tutorials/gomiddleware/) and pass it to the next handler

```
ctxWithUser = context.WithValue(r.Context(), "user", authorizedUser)
rWithUser = r.WithContext(ctxWithUser)
next.ServeHTTP(w, rWithUser)
```

finally in your handler get the request context value

```
ctxUser := r.Context().Value("user").(user.User)
```